# Help finding hosted images

Tags: web-apps

I've been tasked with doing a UX audit with the goal of sunsetting an old site.

One of the tasks includes identifying images that can be sunsetted. This is proving to be tricky because many of the images that are on the old server have been used in pages on the new site - using the old, soon-to-be sunsetted URL.

**Is there a tool or website that could take a hosted image's URL and return a list of pages where that image is being used?**

I've used Google's reverse image search with varying success but because it's not using the URL but the image, it's not a reliable solution, nor is TinEye as the results are not always accurate.

Does this tool exist?

Comment: Could you not copy the site to your local machine and search there?

Comment: No. There's more than 90K pages and TBs of data involved.

Comment: I jsut bought a 12 tB drive for under $200. Of course, it would take a loooong time to D/L a few tB, but it will take even longer to issue search requests from your local PC, so your best solution is something that runs on the server,

Comment: If your site is amenable to web crawling, then a reverse image search *might* work. E.g https://tineye.com/